# Bootstrapped webpage has input disabled due to position:relative

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hello I one simple but annoying problem. I managed to use css and bootsatrap to create the responsive webpage that i wanted. However, when i used position:relative my input (text field) got disabled. Any idea why?

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="logo">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="uv.png">
        </div>

        <div class="login-form">
          <h1>United Volunteers</h1>      
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="input-title">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="input-title">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-input" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>     
      </div>
</div> 

.login-form {
    top:90px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 25px auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:400px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 100px 50px 50px 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #330000;
    z-index: -1;
}

.form-input {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[image: disabled text fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `z-index: -1;`. Its set to negative value.

Just make it positive like:

```
.login-form {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Or look at the snippet below:

```css
.login-form {
    top:90px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 25px auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:400px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 100px 50px 50px 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #330000;
    z-index: 1;
}

.form-input {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="logo">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="uv.png">
        </div>

        <div class="login-form">
          <h1>United Volunteers</h1>      
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="input-title">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="input-title">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-input" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>     
      </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh right forgot to mention, my logo and login button goes under the div tag when i make it positive :(

Comment: @RagnaLugria Can you please attach a working example using fiddle, codepen or stackoverflow's built-in tool?

Comment: ok, so thanks for informing me about my z-index problem. i simply just move it to my #logo. theres no more problem now

Comment: @RagnaLugria Or checkout this link if you have any problem - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLParQ Thanks!